# Alexa Lambda Function "Unable to import module 'index'" when using new required function

Tags: node.js, requirejs, axios, alexa-skills-kit

I'm building an Alexa skill (deploying via CLI), and all has been going well up until needing to make a few Http calls.

I decided to use first axios, then require in order to do so.

When I installed axios using npm, all seemed well. Adding just the "const axios= require('axios');" line caused my lambda function to start complaining about "Unable to import module 'index'" in the Cloudwatch logs, however, and specifically calling out the line in index.js where I make that require statement.

Removed axios, tried require...same deal.

Any thoughts?

Not actually using the packages yet even, it complains on the require line if I uncomment it.

```
/* eslint-disable  func-names */
/* eslint-disable  no-console */
/* eslint-disable  no-restricted-syntax */

const error_handler = require('./error_handler');
const globals = require('./globals');
const helper_functions = require('./helper_functions');
const intents_aquarium = require('./intents_aquarium');
const intents_built_in = require('./intents_built_in');
const intents_conversion = require('./intents_conversion');
const intents_helper = require('./intents_helper');
const intents_tank = require('./intents_tank');
const intents_unhandled = require('./intents_unhandled');

const skillBuilder = globals.Alexa.SkillBuilders.standard();

//const request = require('request');


exports.handler = skillBuilder
  .addRequestHandlers(
    intents_built_in.launchRequest,
    intents_built_in.exitHandler,
    intents_built_in.sessionEndedRequest,
    intents_built_in.helpIntent,
    intents_built_in.yesIntent,
    intents_built_in.noIntent,
    intents_aquarium.aquariumCreateIntentHandler,
    intents_aquarium.aquariumCreateSimpleImperial,
    intents_conversion.aquariumVolumeIntentGallonsToLitres,
    intents_conversion.aquariumVolumeIntentLitresToGallons,
    intents_helper.thankYou,
    intents_tank.tankObservation,
    intents_built_in.fallbackHandler,
    intents_unhandled.unhandledIntent,
  )
  .addErrorHandlers(error_handler.errorHandler)
  .withTableName('Tank-Mate')
  .withAutoCreateTable(true)
  .lambda();
```

Error looks like this:

```
Unable to import module 'index': Error
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:16:17)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

...which to me looks like it's complaining about the index.js require line.

Comment: Can you share the code of your index module? It might just be a syntax error in some other place, unrelated to the axios module.

Comment: I've added the code above. I would prefer to eventually move the require line into the globals.js file, but it barfs there too.

Comment: I can see the packages in my node modules just fine, and it doesn't complain about the ask-sdk which comes in the same way